# Slow mySQL Select Count(*), is there an alternative?

Tags: mysql

The mySQL query below works correctly but it runs very slow. Can anyone please suggest a query that is logically equivalent, but that would run faster.
At least one of column1/column2 will be populated, it may be either or both.
Thank you.

```
UPDATE table2 SET count_of_matches = 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1
WHERE table2.index_id = table1.column1_table2index_id 
   OR table2.index_id = table1.column2_table2index_id)
```

Comment: Is there overlap?  That is, might `SUM(table2.index_id = table1.column1_table2index_id) + SUM(table2.index_id = table1.column2_table2index_id)` give the same COUNT?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:  De-clutter the names.

```
UPDATE  b SET ct = 
    ( SELECT  COUNT(*)
            FROM  a
            WHERE  b.x = a.y1
               OR  b.x = a.y2 )
```

Step 2:  See if this gets the correct counts:

```
SELECT y, SUM(ct) as y_ct
   FROM ( 
      SELECT y1 AS y, COUNT(*) AS y_ct FROM a GROUP BY y1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT y2,      COUNT(*)         FROM a GROUP BY y2
        ) AS u
```

Step 3:  Put step 2 into a "multi-table" Update:

```
UPDATE b
    JOIN (
        SELECT y, SUM(y_ct) as y_ct
           FROM ( 
              SELECT y1 AS y, COUNT(*) AS y_ct FROM a GROUP BY y1
              UNION ALL
              SELECT y2 AS y, COUNT(*) AS y_ct FROM a GROUP BY y2
                ) AS a2
         ) AS a3  ON a3.y = b.x
    SET b.ct = a3.y_ct;
```

Step 0:  Have some indexes:

```
a: INDEX(y1), INDEX(y2)
b: INDEX(x)
```